# Returning Strings from Questions/Answers files

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a Java program for search that uses the Wolfram Alpha API. It stores the Questions in one text file and the Answers in another. I'm attempting to incorporate a feature that will tell the user if the question was previously asked & to provide the user with the saved answer (rather than search Wolfram Alpha).

`Questions.list` and `Answers.list` both store the the input/output on the same corresponding lines. I'm using the following code to output the result:

```
ArrayList<Question> searchArray = prevQuest(userInput);
int index = searchList(searchArray, userInput);

if(index >=0){ //tells program which arraylist to search and the string to search for.
  System.out.println("This question has already been asked. The previous answer was:");
  previousAnswers.get(index).print();
  askQuestion(); // runs method again to avoid doing a WAlpha Search.
```

I'm also using this method:

```
public static int searchList(ArrayList<Question> list, String userInput){
  int j =-1;


  for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++) {
    if(list.get(i).getQuestion().substring(0, list.get(i).getQuestion().length()).equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)){
      j=i;
    }

  return j-1;
```

It returns the incorrect archived answer to the question asked - e.g. If I previously asked who invented the car - It will say "This Q has already been Asked. The previous answer was: Kurt Cobain. Where I may have asked this in a previous question. If I change `return J-1` to `return J`. It gives me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at AssignmentPart7.askQuestion(AssignmentPart7.java:79)
    at AssignmentPart7.main(AssignmentPart7.java:20)
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Or a better way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What line of code is throwing this exception?

Comment: @jzd `previousAnswers.get(index).print();`

Comment: could you format your code, that would be more readable

Comment: Says it right here `.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3`. You're trying to access index 3 when size is only 3. Max index is 2 of list size 3

Comment: @peeskillet That's correct. And that is also the reason I changed 'return j' to 'return j-1' However, when I do so it retrieves to wrong String from Answers.list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question list and answer list must actually have different lengths or your `searchList` has a bug. Your `searchList` method is returning and index of 3 as a match but you only have 3 items in your answer list.

Also, returning `j` is correct as opposed to `j-1` which will actually return the wrong index.

Comment: Thanks jzd. It's quite strange. When I use j-1 it returns the incorrect answer, even where both lists are the same size - e.g. 5 x lines on each, with Q & A both occupying the same corresponding 1 line on each list.

Comment: It shouldn't be strange. j-1 is one off of where it should be. You shouldn't need to modify j.